# Unable to Get Lightning Datatable Columns in Inline Edit Event

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable

I am new to building a Lightning Web Component and I have what feels like a basic validation using the row's data for inline editing, but I have been unable to figure out. I have a simple table with a few columns which I am fetching via a simple Apex SOQL call. Here is the relevant code, which works fine minus the validation check.

Component

```
<lightning:datatable aura:id="reorderTable"
                     data="{! v.reorderList }"
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                     keyField="Id"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                     onsave="{!c.handleSave}" />
```

Column Setup

```
component.set('v.mycolumns', [
    {label: 'Inventory Item', fieldName: 'ProductName', type: 'text'},
    {label: 'Quantity Ordered', fieldName: 'Quantity__c', type: 'number'},
    {label: 'Quantity Received', fieldName: 'QuantityReceived__c', type: 'number', editable: true},
    {label: 'Notes', fieldName: 'Notes__c', type: 'text', wrapText: true, editable: true}
]);
```

Save Event Function

```
var updatedRecords = component.find( "reorderTable" ).get( "v.draftValues" );  
for(var i = 0 ; i < updatedRecords.length;i++) {
    var row = updatedRecords[i];
    var notesError = false;
    if(row.QuantityReceived__c < row.Quantity__c){
        row.ShipmentStatus__c = 'Partial';
        if(row.Notes__c == ''){
            notesError = true;
        }
    }
    else if (row.QuantityReceived__c > row.Quantity__c){
        row.ShipmentStatus__c = 'Pending';
    }
    else{
        row.ShipmentStatus__c = 'Closed';
    }
}
```

So the issue is how do I get the value of an unedited column that should be used for comparison? In this case the field QuantityReceived__c is edited but the Quantity__c field is read only, but that isn't captured in the draftvalues. In a similar vein the Notes__c field is only required if the QuantityReceived__c value is less than the Quantity__c column so it may or may not be in the draftvalues. I realize I could do some of this in the Apex class that does the update, but I was hoping to find a way of not needing to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The draftValues will always include the key-field (typically Id), so you can find the old values from the original data:

```
const updatedRecords = component.find("reorderTable").get("v.draftValues");
const reorderList = component.get("v.reorderList");
updatedRecords.forEach((newRecord) => {
  const oldRecord = reorderList.find((record) => newRecord.Id === record.Id);
  if (newRecord.QuantityReceived__c < oldRecord.Quantity__c) {
    newRecord.ShipmentStatus__c = "Partial";
    if (!row.Notes__c) {
      notesError = true;
    }
  } else if (row.QuantityReceived__c > oldRecord.Quantity__c) {
    newRecord.ShipmentStatus__c = "Pending";
  } else {
    newRecord.ShipmentStatus__c = "Closed";
  }
});
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thank you very much!